# Oracle SQL / How to find duplicate in a child table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a statement that list dept and whether they have duplicate employees (a duplicate employee is when 2 or more records have the same First and Last Name, other columns are ignored)

I have these 3 tables:

T1: Dept
T2: Emp
T3: Party_Rel
Note: T3 serves as an intersection of Table 1 and 2

```
Dept:
Id   | DeptName
---- | --------
1    | Sales
2    | Marketing
3    | Finance

Emp:
Id   | EmpFirstName | EmpLastName
---- | ------------ | ------
1    | Hope         | Smith
2    | Judith       | Bolt
3    | Nathalie     | Meyers
4    | Nathalie     | Meyers
5    | Helen        | Chute

Party_Rel:
Id   | DeptId | EmpId
---- | ------ | -----
1    | 1      | 1
2    | 1      | 2  
3    | 3      | 3  
4    | 3      | 4
5    | 1      | 5
6    | 3      | 5
```

so:
Sales has 2 employees
Marketing has 0 employee
Finance has 3 employees and 2 have the same First+Last Name

the result of  my query would look like:

```
DeptId | DeptName     | DuplicateCheck
------ | ------------ | ----------- 
1      | Sales        | Pass
2      | Marketing    | N/A
3      | Finance      | Fail
```

Sales has 3 employees and they are all unique, therefore DuplicateCheck = 'PASS'
Marketing has 0 employee therefore DuplicateCheck = 'N/A'
Finance has 3 employees and 2 of them are duplicate, therefore DuplicateCheck = 'Fail'

I don't know to build the SQL to display DuplicateCheck:
My 1st problem is that intersection table between Dept and Emp, I don't know how to use it.
My 2nd problem is how to convert the result of the duplicate check into display values (Pass, N/A or Fail).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation for this:

```
select d.id as DeptId, 
    d.deptName,
    case when count(p.id) = 0 then 'N/A'
        when count(distinct e.id) = count(distinct e.empfirstname || ';' || e.emplastname) then 'Pass'
        else 'Fail'
    end as duplicatecheck
from Dept d
left join party_rel p on d.id = p.deptId
left join emp e on p.empId = e.id
group by d.id, d.deptName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Count analytic function is handy to check duplicates.

```
select deptid, deptname, decode(sum(c), -1, 'N/A', 0, 'Pass', 'Fail') duplicatecheck
from (
select d.id deptid, d.deptname, e.empfirstname, e.emplastname,
    count(e.id) over (partition by d.id, e.empfirstname, e.emplastname) - 1 c
from dept d, emp e, party_rel p
where p.deptid (+) = d.id and p.empid = e.id (+)
)
group by deptid, deptname;
```